# Uniqueness/Existence of ODE $y'(t) = \frac{1}{2 y(t)}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How do you show that the ODE $y'(t) = \frac{1}{2 y(t)}$ with the initial condition $y(0) = 0$ has a solution? Note $y'(t)$ is infinity when $t=0$ by the initial condition. However, $y(t) = \sqrt{t}$ is a solution to the ODE. How do you show the ODE has a solution rigorously from theorems, etc.? Thank you.

Comment: The ODE is separable. I'm not sure it's justified to say that the $y(0)=0$ condition is satisfied _per se_, only that $\lim_{t\to 0^+}y(t)=0$.

Comment: Note that $(\sqrt t)'$ is problematic at $t = 0$; not sure we can really call $\sqrt t$ a solution there.  Cheers

Comment: https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/~tyson/existence.pdf is really relevant. Scroll down to see the examples where existence and uniqueness fails. In your case, because the initial condition $y_0 = 0$ fails to exist, the solution is not unique when that condition is specified.